# Run arbitrary Python after 'py' command

Tags: python, powershell

Suppose I have the following Fowershell function:

```
  function test {
        py
        print('hello world')
    }
```

when run, it opens Python in Powershell, but it doesn't execute the code following the 'py' command. how can I make it do that **WITHOUT** creating a file?

Edit: after quitting python, it outputs `Unable to initialize device PRN`. I think it's executing print() after py closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [`-c`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) command line flag:

```
python -c "print('hello world');print('Second line')"                                                                                                                             
>> hello world
>> Second line
```